# Comparing lambda captures in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, lambda

Giving the C# code:

```
int x = 10;

Func<int> next = () => { return ++x; };

Console.WriteLine("Before lambda, x = {0}", x);
Console.WriteLine("The successor of {0} is {1}", x, next());
Console.WriteLine("After lambda,  x = {0} \n", x);
```

The output is:

```
Before lambda, x = 10
The successor of 10 is 11
After lambda,  x = 11
```

After the lambda, the value of x is affected by the lambda action so, this is the equivalent of passing an argument to a function by reference.

Let's compare with Java:

```
interface Inc
{
    int Increment();
}

int x = 10;
Inc next = () -> { return ++x; };

System.out.println("Before lambda, x = " + x);
System.out.println("The successor of " + x + " is " + next.Increment()); // ERROR: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
System.out.println("After lambda,  x = " + x + "\n");
```

If I change the lambda to this:

```
Inc next = () -> { return x+1; };
```

The output is:

```
Before lambda, x = 10
The successor of 10 is 11
After lambda,  x = 10
```

After the lambda, the value of x is NOT affected by the lambda action so, this is the equivalent of passing an argument to a function by value.

What are the technical reasons that prevent Java to alter a captured variable.

I know what the error message says:

***«local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final»***

But this is not enough to me. What the technical reason behind that?

What are the consequences if Java allows that captured variables may be altered by the lambda?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java and the JVM doesn't support references to local variables. What the compiler could do is translate the variable into a reference, but it doesn't.

e.g. it could translate your code like this.

```
int[] x = { 10 };
IntSupplier next = () -> { return ++x[0]; };

System.out.println("Before lambda, x = " + x);
System.out.println("The successor of " + x + " is " + next.getAsInt()); // 
System.out.println("After lambda,  x = " + x + "\n");
```

How if you really need this you could change the code yourself.

BTW One of the key features of functional programming is to use pure functions where ever possible.  Pure functions don't have side effects.  While Java doesn't have any way to enforce pure functions, iMHO it would seem that adding a way to have subtle side effects wouldn't be consistent with adding functional constructs.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with side effects, because the variable is captured by value, so, inside the lambda we have a copy of the variable.

Comment: @ArnbjorgJohansen Exactly, you have a *copy* of the variable, which means that you cannot update the original. To prevent you from mistakenly thinking that updating the copy would update the original, the language designers made the great decision to require the variable to be *(effectively)* `final` (immutable), so you *can't* make the mistake. --- Hmmm... I guess that's the answer to *"What the technical reason behind that?"*

Comment: @ArnbjorgJohansen A change in state is a side effect.